# A word for the person after whom someone or something is named

Tags: single-word-requests

I believe it's a common practice in some communities to name children after their grandparents or parents or relatives and sometimes even friends and popular people. Places, roads, streets etc., get named after famous people, too. Many inventions and discoveries have been named after people who invented or discovered them.

But I am not yet aware of a term that refers to the person whose name is given to people, places or objects this way. Is there a suitable word to fill in the blank below?

> They named their son after the famous football player, David Beckham.
>
> David Beckham is .......... of their son.

Comment: Eponym? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eponym http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/eponym

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: @Kris I wondered that. Perhaps it wouldn't have happened if "David Beckham" had been "King David I of Scotland".

Comment: I also wondered about _eponym_, but I don't think it's right.

Comment: The downvotes are perhaps because my question sounds too basic. But I am not an expert on English. Anyway, I think Kris's comment has the right word – [Eponym](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/eponym?q=eponym)

Comment: The perfectly good (for AmE) answer *namesake* is being downvoted as well. Maybe people are feeling mean today.

Comment: I'd use *eponym* for somebody after whom *something* is named, but not for somebody after whom *someone* is named. I'd use *namesake* for this. But this is just AmE.

Comment: @PeterShor Every eponym is a namesake; every namesake is **not** an eponym.

Comment: @Kris: This is definitely correct by dictionary definition. But his is my impression of how the words are actually used in AmE, and not the dictionary definitions.

Comment: How about the name for a person named after a situation, like Johnny Castaway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OED has this for *eponym*:

> **1.a.** One who gives, or is supposed to give, his name to a people, place, or institution; e.g. among the Greeks, the heroes who were looked upon as ancestors or founders of tribes or cities.

and this for *protonym*:

> The first person or thing of a certain name; something from which another person or thing takes its name.

The distinction appears to be that with *eponym*, the later thing takes its name from **a direct relationship** with the earlier thing; whereas with *protonym* the second thing has simply **been given the same name** as the first.

Wikipedia gives an example:

> A synonym of *eponym* is *namegiver* (not to be confused with *namesake*.) Someone who (or something that) is referred to with the adjective *eponymous* is the eponym of something. An example is: "Léon Theremin, the eponymous inventor of the theremin."

OED has this:

> 1880   *Scribner's Monthly* Mar. 667/2:  "The wrecked canal-boat, the Evening Star,..quenched in the twilight, with its heavenly protonym palpitating in the vapor above it."

The instrument called the theremin **takes its name** from its eponymous ("name-giving") inventor; whereas the boat *Evening Star* was simply **given the existing name** of an unrelated thing.

In the question, David Beckham is the ***protonym*** of the child.

In British English, the word *namesake* is a "bi-directional" relation: David Beckham and the child are namesakes. It appears from the Wikipedia entry that in American English *namesake* can mean protonym as well, and imply a uni-directional relationship.

Comment: Just realized OED here refers to Oxford English Dictionary. Probably just me - first time seeing this acronym.

Answer (score 6):

"David Beckham is the *[namesake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namesake)* of their son."

Comment: But _namesake_ refers to anyone with the same name. Right?

Comment: Apparently *namesake* is sometimes used in this way in American English. In BrE it does mean "anyone with the same name". See Kris's comment on the question, which should really be an answer.

Comment: At least *namesake* should be bidirectional - we need a one way relation, right?

Comment: @AndrewLeach: Yes, Kris said it right (with link).

Comment: +1: Why the downvotes? Why should there be a unidirectional word? In American English, *namesake* is often used for this (much more often than *eponym* is), and it's very rare that there's any confusion about which direction is meant. See [*Merriam-Webster*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/namesake?show=0&t=1357994180). And anyway, there is a unidirectional word: *eponym,* which @Kris should post as an answer.

Comment: @PeterShor: I quite agree. And I am wondering why Kris did not post it as an answer.

Comment: @InglishTeeture: No, namesake is specific, and, as far as I know, it can refer to the person who you are named after.

Comment: Tylerharms, the problem here is if a child is named David after King David I as Andrew Leach mentioned, which of them would be the *namesake*? Both? If so, how to know the difference without further context? And what about all the Davids of the world?

Comment: Well, in the David Beckham example, it's pretty clear. With context, I don't see how it wouldn't be clear. Frankly, I'm surprised it's receiving so much criticism. As an American, it comes quite naturally to me. I'm learning, though, that it's not. That said, I like eponym real well, but I think the sentence "David Beckham is the eponym of their son" sounds a little clunky.

Comment: @Kris: they would be the *namesakes* of each other. It doesn't cause any confusion at all when used this way in American English. Context straightens everything out.

Comment: @PeterShor, 'Why should there be a unidirectional word?' No reason, but the question was seeking a unidirectional word, so if there isn't one, then the answer to the question is 'There is no such word'.

Comment: The two dictionaries I just checked each give the same two meanings for "namesake".  One is the symmetrization of "eponym" and the other is the converse of "eponym". Neither agrees with "eponym".

Comment: @jsw29: the OP is not asking for a unidirectional word. In his post, nowhere does he mention that it has to be unidirectional. "Namesake" is the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

After 5 decades of speaking American English I'd have to say that "namesake" is the only natural and perfectly correct choice when the referents are all people. But given how widespread its casual use to indicate nothing more than same-namedness is, the connotation "the person someone is named after" is only understood through context. And easily so. Yet it remains fair to say the language simply lacks a word with the specificity I believe the questioner was after.

Answer (score 0):

Namesake is ancestry, not accident. Some random person with same two names as me is just that, but Facebook and Gmail have collapsed the world of names. I propose the two neologisms for a stackexchange vote:

nompelganger or homynamer

Comment: Welcome to ELL. I don't think you have really answered the question that was being asked. Have a look around and see how questions are answered and how we like to include evidence in our answers which show that it is not just a personal opinion.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the correct answer is a French language term I came across years ago, the meaning of which is "the one whom I am named after."  I don't remember the word, unfortunately, but it was along the lines of "auber....auberjonior"?  Something like that.  Similar to the name of actor Rene Auberjonios.