# Onomastics /Onomatology (personal names)

Tags: single-word-requests

What is an onomastic (or onomatological) term for given names consisting of the names of famous people, e.g.:

> Winfield Scott Hancock;
>   Washington Roebling,
>   etc.

... where the *protonym* of Hancock is Winfield Scott, and that of Roebling is George Washington?

Comment: What are you asking? Also, formulate a proper title, don't just subvert the filter. Creating a better title and question helps *you*.

Comment: Patronymics (named after patrons rather than fathers)?  There's an Eighteenth Century verse:  "Julius Caesar Pompey Green wore a jacket of Velveteen." I look forward to hearing the answer as I have two great-uncles Stanley, Vernon who are either named after either explorers or geographical features, and now it's too late to ask which.

Comment: Are you looking for the term *namesake*? --but that refers to the person from whom the name is taken, not to the name itself.

Comment: Is Onomastics / Onomatology a large enough branch of semantics to be given a tag?

Comment: @Hugh I imagine the decision to create tags is predicated more on how many questions he site receives on a given topic, rather than how large the academic discipline is (though of course I'm practice the former will be partially reflective of the latter).

Answer (score 2):

Given that the first example of a name (such as *Washington* in the question) is the [*protonym*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/protonym), one obvious name for followers is ***deuteronym.***

> Second: Deutero-Isaiah
>   Secondary: *deuterocanonical*
>
> From Greek *deuteros* 'second'.
>
> [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/deutero-)

The term has appeared with this meaning elsewhere (on [answers.com](http://www.answers.com/Q/When_did_Israelites_become_Israelis)), so it's not entirely new.

Answer (score 1):

If what you mean to ask is if there is a special term for names of historical people/role models that have been taken as an inspiration for naming a child (and not as a nickname), then no, I don't believe there is.

N.B.: A 'protonym' is something entirely different, though, although I can see what you mean.

Comment: This is actually wrong, because the name of the earlier person, which is then taken by others, [**is** the protonym](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/97668/18696).